# LOOP AT... GROUP BY with dynamic group key

Tags: grouping, abap

I am trying to loop by grouping data with dynamic group parameter.

We can use dynamic queries on WHERE conditions on loops but I do not know whether it is possible to use a dynamic string in group condition.

Here is the sample where user decides by which field to group and then put additional logic based on the decision:

```
DATA query TYPE string.
IF i_condition_type = 'ERNAM'.
  query = |ERNAM = MARA-ERNAM|.
ELSE.
  query = |ERSDA = MARA-ERSDA|.
ENDIF.

LOOP AT lt_mara INTO DATA(mara) GROUP BY ( (query) ) "syntax error
                                ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<group>).
  LOOP AT GROUP <group> ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<line_data>).
    "//do something
  ENDLOOP.
ENDLOOP.
```

Is there any way to do this? I am also open to other ideas besides grouping because if I can't dynamically group, I will copy so many lines and change only the group key.

Comment: or group dynamically on database level https://stackoverflow.com/a/61063867/911419 and then use the same loop on already grouped dataset

Comment: @SandraRossi There are ways to do `GROUP BY` dynamically which don't exactly work with strings as conditions but can do a lot of things you would usually use dynamic conditions for. If you are interested, check out my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, `LOOP AT ... GROUP BY` doesn't support dynamic group-by clauses from strings.

In this simple example you could create your grouping key dynamically at runtime by creating it with an inline expression like `COND` or `SWITCH`:

```
LOOP AT lt_mara INTO DATA(mara) GROUP BY 
    SWITCH string(
       i_condition_type
       WHEN 'ERNAM' THEN mara-ernam
       WHEN 'ERSDA' THEN mara-ersda
       ELSE ''
     )
```

But your key-building logic might be too complex to express with an expression (or at least an expression which is still readable by a human being). In that case there is something else you can do: group on values returned by a method:

```
LOOP AT lt_mara INTO DATA(mara) 
     GROUP BY my_grouping_method( line = mara 
                                  condition = i_condition_type )
```

The implementation of that method can then include any logic you need to form the grouping key at runtime:

```
METHOD my_grouping_method.
  IF condition = 'ERNAM'.
    result = line-ernam.
  ELSE.
    result = line-ersda.
  ENDIF.    
ENDMETHOD.
```

The grouping method can also be a method of a different object. So you could represent your grouping condition as an own class. That would allow you to write code like this:

```
 DATA(lo_group_condition) = NEW zcl_mara_group_condition( 'ERNAM' ). 

 LOOP AT lt_mara INTO DATA(mara) 
     GROUP BY lo_group_condition->get_key_from( mara )
```

Comment: It should be noted that first approach (COND/SWITCH) is good only for simple group keys, it cannot handle composite ones like `GROUP BY ( key1 = key1 key2 = key2 key3 = key3 ... ) `

Comment: @Philipp To return 3 condition how you will do in the method? Thanks

Comment: @ekekakos Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: How to do the below  rbukrs = wa_acdoca-rbukrs
belnr = wa_acdoca-belnr
gjahr = wa_acdoca-gjahr ).   The parameter LINE in your example is type TABLE?  
And the RESULT what type is it? Thanks

Comment: @ekekakos Yes, the `line` import parameter would be the line-type of your table. `result` can be whatever you want. When you want to group by multiple values in your grouping functions, then I would concatenate them into a string. Or maybe the grouping function can return a structure? I would have to try that.

Comment: Very interesting trick; I can't get it to work though. I'm using the following syntax: `LOOP AT lt_test ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_dummy>) GROUP BY lcl_test=>get_group_key( ) ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs>).` and `<fs>` contains the literal names of the keys instead of their values. The function returns the string `'<FS_DUMMY>-NAME'`.

Comment: @Cutter The method after `GROUP BY` gets executed for every line and returns **the value** that's used to assign that table line to a group. Returning a string with the name of a field doesn't make any sense in this context. If you need more help with solving your current problem, please open a new question.