# ABAP String Templates - Embedded Expressions with GROUP BY

Tags: group-by, abap

I am refering to this question: [LOOP AT... GROUP BY with dynamic group key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62956466/loop-at-group-by-with-dynamic-group-key)

I also want to do some dynamic GROUP-BY-Aggregations.

I want to dynamize a GROUP-BY-Statement like the following snippet:

```
      WHEN 'vkorg'.

        LOOP AT ls_output-merged_data INTO ls_tmp
          GROUP BY (  sales_org = ls_tmp-sales_org
                      group_quantity = GROUP SIZE )

           ASCENDING ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_tmp_2>).

          lt_tmp_dim1 = VALUE #( BASE lt_tmp_dim1 (
                              sales_org = <fs_tmp_2>-sales_org
                              group_quantity  = <fs_tmp_2>-group_quantity
                              ) ).
        ENDLOOP.
```

Curently I have some smiliar to this:

```
  LOOP AT ls_output-merged_data INTO ls_tmp
      GROUP BY COND #( WHEN iv_dim1 EQ 'vkorg' THEN |{ ls_tmp-sales_org }| ) 


                               ASCENDING ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<total_group>).


    LOOP AT GROUP <total_group> ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<line_data>).
      ASSIGN COMPONENT 'vkorg' OF STRUCTURE <line_data> TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<vkorg>).
      EXIT.
    ENDLOOP.




  ENDLOOP.
```

The issue here is, that I also need the GROUP SIZE field. However I am not able to put it into the embedded expression like: |{ ls_tmp-sales_org GROUP SIZE }|

I tried several positions and syntax but I was not able to make it work.

Does someone did something similiar before and can help me out?

Comment: Doesn't it work: `GROUP BY ( sales_org = COND #( WHEN iv_dim1 EQ 'vkorg' THEN |{ ls_tmp-sales_org }| ) group_quantity = GROUP SIZE )`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Sandra it works now:

```
  LOOP AT ls_output-merged_data INTO ls_tmp
      GROUP BY ( sales_org = COND #( WHEN iv_dim1 EQ 'vkorg' THEN |{ ls_tmp-sales_org }| ) 
                 group_quantity = GROUP SIZE  )

           ASCENDING ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<total_group>).




  ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. You may also **accept the answer** so that to make it clear.